# Question about convergence of integrals

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Is the following correct, or am I missing something?

$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x}$ does not converge if we include the end point $0$. On the other hand, $\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dx}{x}\ ,\ \epsilon>0$ does converge to $-log(\epsilon)$. As long as you integrate on the semi-open interval $(0,1]$, there is convergence. If you integrate on the closed interval $[0,1]$, there is divergence.

In other words, we have:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x}\neq\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dx}{x}\ ,\ \epsilon>0$$

but we can say:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x}= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x}$$

What is interesting here is that the integrals on the semi-open $(0,1]$ all converge (have a definite value $<\infty$), yet the integral on the closed $[0,1]$ diverges to $+\infty$. Is that a correct way of seeing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (mostly) correct, though you need to be a bit careful.  Integrals do not distinguish between open and closed integrals, so saying that you obtain a different result when integrating on $(0,1]$ vs. $[0,1]$ doesn't make sense.  It is true, however, that $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x}\neq\int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{dx}{x}\ ,\ \varepsilon>0$$ because the integral on the left diverges and the integral on the right converges.  What that means is that the integral diverges on $[0,1]$ (or equivalently $(0,1],[0,1)$, or $(0,1)$) and converges on the interval $[\varepsilon,1]$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.  However, it is also worth noting that since $$\int_{\varepsilon}^{1} \frac{dx}{x} = -\log(\varepsilon),\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}-\log(\varepsilon) = \infty,$$ we recover the divergent case as we let $\varepsilon \to 0$ as expected.

Comment: You said "mostly correct" - which parts did I miss? Only that integrating doesn't distinguish between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Just your sentence about convergence on $(0,1]$ and divergence on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But we can say that $\forall \epsilon >0$, the integral on $[\epsilon,1]$ has a finite value, whereas the integral on $[0,1]$ has an infinite value, right? In other words, the limit point $0$ is the only "arbiter" of convergence (?).

Comment: (see my latest edit about "arbiter" :-) "Closing" the interval leads to divergence?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dx}{x}$ doesn't converge because we're not taking any kind of limit here. You are correct it's value is $-\ln (\epsilon)$ though.

However, if you take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, then $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1\frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} - \ln (\epsilon) = - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln \epsilon = \infty$$

With lower bound $\epsilon > 0$, the integral is proper, so there's no issue.

Comment: Well, one definition (interpretation?) of integrals involves a limit process (with staircase functions of reducing step sizes), so in that sense, I can say that the integral from $\epsilon$ to $1$ converges, meaning that it has a finite value, as opposed to being divergent, in which case the limit of the Darboux sums would not be finite.